# How to Resize the Default Resolution of Thumbnails in JS function code for Blogger?

Tags: javascript, thumbnails, blogger

How to Resize the Default Resolution of Thumbnails on below code? with this code i getting very low quality image on my website. so, how to improve image quality with this code?

```js
function getPosts(json) {
  var posts = "<ul class=mbtlist>";
  for (var i = 0; i < json.feed.entry.length; i++) {
    var title = json.feed.entry[i].title.$t;
    var url = json.feed.entry[i].link.pop().href;
    var thumbnail = json.feed.entry[i].media$thumbnail.url;
    posts += "<li>" + 
               "<a class='mbttitle' href='" + url + "'>" + 
                 "<img src='" + thumbnail + "'>" + 
                  title + 
               "</a>" + 
             "</li >";
  }
  posts += '</ul>';
  document.getElementById('container').innerHTML = posts;
}
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
<script src="https://www.sebahotnews.org/feeds/posts/default/-/জাতীয়?max-results=4&alt=json&callback=getPosts"></script>
```

Comment: If the source image is low quality adding image dimensions to the above code will not help

Comment: my another function had this code:  sk= thumbUrl.replace("/s72-c/","/s"+ImageSize+"/");       
  ListImage= "'" + sk.replace("?imgmax=800","") + "'";       
  } (how to add this code on my answered code?)

Comment: How to Resize the Default Resolution of Thumbnails in this JS function code for Blogger?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
<script>
function getPosts(json) {
    var posts = "<ul class=mbtlist>";
    for (var i = 0; i < json.feed.entry.length; i++) {
        var title = json.feed.entry[i].title.$t;
        var url = json.feed.entry[i].link.pop().href;
        if (json.feed.entry[i].media$thumbnail){thumbUrl = json.feed.entry[i].media$thumbnail.url;thumbnail= thumbUrl.replace("/s72-c/","/s"+400+"/");}

posts += "<li><a class='mbttitle' href='" + url + "'><img src='" + thumbnail + "'>" + title + "</a></li>";
    }
   posts+='</ul>';
    document.getElementById('container').innerHTML = posts;
}
</script>
```